# How to use sdkman in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sdkman

I would like to activate a specific set of tools via **SDKMAN** in my scripted `Jenkinsfile` pipeline.

Basically I would like to do

```
node("sdkman && mvn386") {

   sh "sdk use maven 3.8.6"
   sh "sdk current"           // << back to whatever was before
   sh "mvn --version"

   sh "mvn clean install"
}
```

But since `sdk ...` is executed in a subshell the `use` is not active in the next like.

(It would work with `sdk default ...` but that is out of the question, because I do not want to destroy other running pipelines)

Semantically it would be something like this I need (which is not supported, I think):

```
node("sdkman && mvn386") {

   sh ("sdk use maven 3.8.6") { // << unsupported syntax 
     sh "sdk current"           
     sh "mvn --version"

     sh "mvn clean install"
   }
}
```

How can I keep the changes that `sdk` makes to the shell env to the next lines? Is there another tool to use instead of `sh`? Something like `withEnv`?

---

Side problem: Because `sdk` is just a shell function I needed to create a wrapper script `sdh.sh` (containing `sdk $*`). That of course defies the "chaning the environment", too. `sh "sdk ..."` just does not seem to work with shell functions. Any way around that?

---

Something I do **not want to do** is putting the script lines into one block, because that would not work well with our more complicated pipelines.

```
   sh '''
      sdk use maven 3.8.6
      sdk current
      '''  // << I dont want to do this in one shell block
```

Comment: Each invocation of the `sh` step method is a separate shell interpreter sub-process, so you would need to use either of your proposed alternatives (multiline or separate script file). If this `sdk` executable has bindings instead of just a CLI, then you could develop a global var/shared lib for it also.

Comment: @MattSchuchard No Bindings, no. Because it modifies Env Vars in your current shell. Mainly, though, because theoretically it could change other stuff as well. It changes PATH and JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME and whatever that tool requires. So, basically it is doing what `withEnv()` is also doing, except it could be more. Also with `withEnv` I have to list the env vars explicitly. I have the feeling that not even `tool` would really helm me. And `tool` does not seem to work for all tools, just for maven, java and git. So, sdkman is much more flexible in that respect.